# java mail API exception

Tags: java, email

I got this exception when trying to send mail from web application:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Missing 
or literal domains not allowed
```

I am using properties like below code.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.verizon.net");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

I also  authenticate the users using username and password using authenticate method.

I got success message only when i'm authenticate. I got exception when i go to line called `transport.sen(message)`.

```
    this is my full code..



try {

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                    to));
//          message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(
//                  cc));
//          message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC,
//                  new InternetAddress(bcc));
            message.setSubject("TEST...!!!!!!!");

             Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

             BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
             messageBodyPart
             .setText("Dear Sir, Mail Testing");
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


             messageBodyPart.setText("Hao test");
            message.setText("Kader here");
             message.setContent(multipart);


             MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
                mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
                mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
                mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
                mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
                mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
                CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport();

            transport.connect();
            Transport.send(message);
            transport.close();


            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: how are setting the message recipeints, sender and content? please post that code too

Comment: It seems to be something related to verizon. Maybe these helps: http://forums.verizon.com/t5/Verizon-net-Email/Win7-receive-but-no-send/td-p/312309 and http://www.vistax64.com/vista-mail/197859-window-mail-gone-haywire-help.html

Answer (score 1):

There is possibility that Some mail servers automatically append the domain name to the user name when client logging but some server will not, hence fail the authentication.

Comment: i put username like this only..xyz not like this xyz@abc.com

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code  :-

MailUtil.java
------------ 
package com.test;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;  
import java.util.Properties;  
import java.util.logging.Level;  
import java.util.logging.Logger;  
import javax.mail.Authenticator;  
import javax.mail.Message;  
import javax.mail.MessagingException;  
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;  
import javax.mail.Session;  
import javax.mail.Transport;  
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;  
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;  

/**
   * Please test with your GMAIL
   * @author Jamsheer T
   * +91-9846716175
   *
   */

public class MailUtil {  

private String SMTP_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";  
private String FROM_ADDRESS = "jamsheer568@gmail.com";  //Give Your  gmail here 
private String PASSWORD = "***********";  //Give Your password here
private String FROM_NAME = "Jamsheer T";  

  public boolean sendMail(String[] recipients, String[] bccRecipients, String subject, 

  String message) {  
    try {  
        Properties props = new Properties();  
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST);  
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
        props.put("mail.debug", "false");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");  
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new SocialAuth());  
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);  

        InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress(FROM_ADDRESS, FROM_NAME);  
        msg.setFrom(from);  

        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];  
        for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {  
            toAddresses[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);  
        }  
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);  


        InternetAddress[] bccAddresses = new InternetAddress[bccRecipients.length];  
        for (int j = 0; j < bccRecipients.length; j++) {  
            bccAddresses[j] = new InternetAddress(bccRecipients[j]);  
        }  
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccAddresses);  

        msg.setSubject(subject);  
        msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");  
        Transport.send(msg);  
        return true;  
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {  
        ex.printStackTrace();

        Logger.getLogger(MailUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
        return false;  

    } catch (MessagingException ex) {  
        ex.printStackTrace();

        Logger.getLogger(MailUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);  
        return false;  
    }  
}  

class SocialAuth extends Authenticator {  


    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  

        return new PasswordAuthentication(FROM_ADDRESS, PASSWORD);  

    }  
   }  
  }

 Main.java
 ----------------
 package com.test;


 public class Main {  

   public static void main(String[] args) {  
   String[] recipients = new String[]{"example1@gmail.com"};  //To
   String[] bccRecipients = new String[]{"example2@gmail.com"};  //Bcc
   String subject = "Test Mail";  //Subject
   String messageBody = "Hi how  r  u?????";  //Body


      System.out.print("Result"+new MailUtil().sendMail(recipients, bccRecipients, 

  subject, messageBody));

   }  
   }
```